# Hide Projects in .sbt

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have the following declarations in my .sbt file:

```scala
lazy val root = (Project("core", file("."))
    aggregate(project1, project2)
    settings (...))
lazy val project1 = Project("project1", file("project1"))
lazy val project2 = Project("project2", file("project2"))
lazy val project3 = Project("project3", file("project3"))
```

I want by default to have project3 hidden to sbt (and of course Intellij IDEA project), and only have it visible after enabling it via a system property like `-Dproject3.enabled=true`. Any ideas how to implement such forking?

Comment: I think synthetic project feature of sbt 0.13.13 can be used in this situation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Synthetic+subprojects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign your subproject conditionally:

```scala
lazy val project3 = if (System.getProperty("project3.enabled") == "true") {
  Project("project3", file("project3"))
} else {
  // This is just a cheat to get the type system working. There might be
  // a cleaner way to do this.
  root
}
```